# Why can't I use hybrid-sleep?

Tags: kubuntu, 18.04, suspend, swap, partitioning

In Kubuntu 18.04 I have created a swap space that is operational already, as in the KDE partition manager it has the option "Deactivate swap", which means it is activated.

Also, I can see this:

```
$ swapon -s
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile                               file            1698080 0       -2
/dev/sda6                               partition       4245500 0       -3
```

meaning I also have a swap *file* beside the *partition*.

Those together show a 5804 MB of swap memory, which is free:

```
$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3860        1620         247         180        1992        2156
Swap:          5804           0        5804
```

But hybrid-sleep doesn't work:

```
~$ systemctl hybrid-sleep
Failed to put system into hybrid sleep via logind: Access denied
```

It asks for password, freezes the computer for a few moments and then fails (unlike `systemctl suspend` and `systemctl poweroff` which do not require password and do not fail).

---

**Edit after answer.**
Note that:

- I have a dual boot with Windows 10
- Fast boot is disabled in Windows.
- Legacy bios is used, not UEFI,  and I do not have UEFI settings in Windows.

My partition scheme looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Seems obvious that you can't use it because it doesn't work.

Comment: @mikewhatever - the question is "why?"

Answer (score 4):

**Please check whether your system supports hybrid suspend.** In terminal, type

```
sudo pm-is-supported --suspend-hybrid && echo "Hybrid suspend is supported" || echo "Your system doesn't support hybrid suspend"
```

> If the output gets **Hybrid suspend is supported**, continue in terminal.

```
sudo nano /etc/pm/config.d/00-use-suspend-hybrid
```

Then paste the following code into the blank area using `ctrl` + `shift` + `v`.

```
if [ "$METHOD" = "suspend" ]; then
METHOD=suspend_hybrid
fi
PM_HIBERNATE_DELAY=900
```

> PM_HIBERNATE_DELAY stands for time in seconds until hibernation occurs.

Now save the file using `ctrl` + `o` and exit using `ctrl` + `x`.

---

**Disable Windows fast startup in dual boot setup.**

> Windows users will likely see complications with dual boot and virtualization. Furthermore, some users have even reported that power buttons on their keyboard will not work and fans in their PSs will continue spinning.

**[Full article](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/dual-boot-vs-virtual-machine/)**

---

**Since it's a kernel related thing, you can still change the kernel, to see if it works.**

---

**This [answer](https://superuser.com/a/421040) may help you as well.**

Comment: it seems it does not support it: `sudo: pm-is-supported: command not found
Your system doesn't support hybrid suspend`. Is that a hardware limitation? Which exactly?

Comment: @cipricus maybe you are using Secure Boot, if so, disable it. It is a kernel-related issue, so you can still change the kernel to see if it works.

Comment: you mean windows secure boot?

Comment: @cipricus yes, I mean, is kubuntu the only OS running on your setup?

Comment: I do have Windows 10, but no uefi settings, in fact I have legacy bios. But is the issue the same with the fast boot feature of Win10? or is it another issue?

Comment: ah okay :/ so I am going back to this when I get back home..

Comment: your first answer was possibly  helpful. while posting a link is not a proper answer, the linked answer has little to do with my case. windows is nor hibernating, but is fully shut down. grub2 is the bootloader, administered from linux. i do have a boot partition of windows. I will post my  partition scheme.

Comment: @cipricus edited the answer as it was before. I will get to this again shortly after I'll finish dual boot setup on my mashine.

Comment: @user47206 command not found means you need install 'pm-utils'